# django rest framework OPTIONS 500

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting a strange 500 error when issuing an OPTION request to an endpoint in my API built with Django Rest Framework. GET, POST, PUT all work fine and DELETE is not allowed.

When issuing an OPTION request to the endpoint, I get the following error and traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  85.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  452.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  449.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in options
  463.         data = self.metadata_class().determine_metadata(request, self)
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py" in determine_metadata
  63.             actions = self.determine_actions(request, view)
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py" in determine_actions
  89.                 actions[method] = self.get_serializer_info(serializer)
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py" in get_serializer_info
  106.             for field_name, field in serializer.fields.items()
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py" in <listcomp>
  106.             for field_name, field in serializer.fields.items()
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py" in get_field_info
  129.         if hasattr(field, 'choices'):
File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in choices
  382.             for item in iterable

Exception Type: TypeError at /v1/powerChatSessions
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is the model, serializer, and view:

```
# models.py - error happens when issuing OPTIONS /powerChatSession
class VideoConversation(models.Model):
    """
    Capture data about a video chat session
    SO note: this is inherited by other classes besides PowerChat
    """
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class PowerChat(VideoConversation):
    """
    power chat session
    """
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    extended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


# serializers.py
class PowerChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PowerChat
        read_only_fields = ('users', 'start', 'extended',)

# views.py
class PowerChatViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PowerChat.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (PowerChatPermission,)
    serializer_class = PowerChatSerializer
    resource_name = "powerChatSession"
```

Any ideas why this is happening? It has something to do with the users field, and it seems that it could be a bug with Django Rest Framework? It's checking if the field has the choices kwarg, which it doesn't, but apparently DRF thinks it does?

Comment: `choices=False` is not valid for a Django field. `choices` must be an iterable object, and more than likely that is what is triggering the error.

Comment: oops, yeah sorry forgot to remove that. Was trying things. Problem exists without that

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue was addressed by:

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3115

The gist is that "At the moment, self.action is None in viewsets if I get an OPTIONS request."

This issue ceased for me after I upgraded to djangorestframework-3.2.3